# Where'd my wireless go?

Tags: wireless-networking, thinkpad, tcpip

Got an old Lenovo R60e running XP Home that I use for misc. wireless tasks around the house.  I had need to print from a fixed workstation to a USB printer in another room.  So, I turned on printer sharing on the Lenovo.  As soon as I applied it, my wifi connection dropped and I can't get it back.  It throws an "error 117 Wireless stack initialization failed" any time I try to connect.  I've rebooted, rolled back,all the obvious things.  Looks like this is something pretty specific, hoping someone here has hit upon a solution for this already.  Also of note, my wired network connection also disappeared.  It's like the whole IP stack took a dump when I turned on printer sharing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried repairing the Intel PROset software?

```
Start -> Programs -> Control Panel
Add or Remove Programs
Scroll down to find the Intel PROSet/Wireless Software
Click Change/Remove
Select Modify and click Next and let it repair.
```

Comment: Score!  I'd done the "uninstall driver" thing in hardware, never thought to try that.  This worked!  Thanks!